# Hover causes jquery submenus to rapidly flicker/flash

Tags: jquery, flash, menu, flicker, submenu

I'm a novice at css, jquery and the like. I purchased a template from ThemeForest and it was working alright until a week ago. Now when I hover over the submenus, they flash or flicker rapidly. I can't figure out what changed, and I certainly haven't made any edits to jquery, especially since I can't even figure out where this code is. I've tried to research this, but being so new to working with code, I'm just not sure where to even begin. I would so appreciate any feedback you might be able to offer.

Here's the site.

http://www.allegrocreative.com/METSS/index.html

Comment: To start with correct the script errors in your site, the developer console shows 2 errors in your file custom.js. The browser cant seem to find the elements with the ids "#social-01" and "#cycle-slider"

Comment: I'm not using those functions, so I went in and deleted the script to find those. Don't know if that was the right thing to do or not. Again, I'm really new to this (hence the reason I bought a template) but the troubleshooting is really frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the `.stop()`-function for the event-queue @ [jquery-Api](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

you should use your animations with ".stop(true,true)" to not fill the queue if somebody hovers a lot over all the menus...

Comment: I did a find and replace for all instances of .stop() and replaced with .stop(true,true), but doesn't seem to be helping. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: first: no you didn't - ther're some points in the code where "stop()" is without the "jump to end and stop current-animation"-bools are set...
second: you'll have to ADD "stop(true,true)" on every-animation where the function is prepended before the animation begins...

for example:
".slideDown()" should become ".stop(true,true).slideDown()" etc.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I'll look for those.